# Datagridviewautofilter working really slow

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wonder why does my DataGridView works really slow because of DataGridViewAutoFilter. I take like 400 items from a MS Access database. Are there any free and trusted alternatives instead of this dll?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this: Datagridview with filtering capability on CodeProject. It seems to work really well.